# How can i exit Phonegap Application for android?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

this function is not working

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

WHILE EXECUTING THE ABOVE LINE ERROR MESSAGE SHOWN AS

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(984)] "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'exec'", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.2.0.js (984).


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PhoneGap</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            function onLoad()
            {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
            }
              function onDeviceReady() {
                document.addEventListener('backbutton', exitFromApp, false);
            }
            function exitFromApp()
            {
                if(navigator.app)
                {
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                }
                else if(navigator.device)
                {
                    navigator.device.exitApp();
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="onLoad();">
        <button name="buttonClick" onclick="exitFromApp()">Click Me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following ( i think `navigator.app` is not avaiable in cordova-2.2.0 ) :

```
if(navigator.app){
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}
else if(navigator.device){
    navigator.device.exitApp();
}
```

Comment: where is your `onDeviceReady` method

Comment: I checked with the onDeviceReady Same error displyed. pls help

Comment: when i use cordovo1.8.0 error shown as

[INFO:CONSOLE(16)] "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exitApp'", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (16)

Comment: may i know which cordovo version is suitable to this exit function.

Comment: I remember using it in Cordova 3.0+